# NodeJS serial iteration over an array of objects

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I have an array of objects that I need to iterate over with a function and for each object. I need to call the function only when the call of the function on the previous object has ended.

Structurally, it would be similar to:

```js
async.forEachOf(arr,iterator,callback);
```

... but it was executed serially.

Any idea how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.forEach()` is synchronous.

If you want a async version, take a look on [this](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)